# Java file io calculating average and storing in another file

Tags: java, io

I would appreciate knowing how to tackle this type of problems. Thank you in advance.
Here is the question.

The first line of the files contains two integer numbers ;
number-of-records                exam-grade

number-of-records        : indicates number of the records in the file.
exam-grade : indicates the grade of the exam.
The file follows by students name and their grades.
Sample File: test1.txt
Contains four records, and the exam is out of 80. The file follows by the name and grade of the students:

```
4  80
Mary 65.5
Jack 43.25
Harry 79.0
Mike 32.5
```

You have to develop the body of following method:

public static void readWrite(String srcfileName,  String dstFileName)

That reads grades of each student from srcFileName, calculates their grade percent, indicates that if student passed or failed, and finally reports the class average, number of the students passed, and number of the students failed the exam and saves the result in dstFileName.
The output file for the previous test file should be:

```
Mary          81.88        passed 
Jack          54.06        passed 
Harry         98.75        passed 
Mike          40.63        failed 
class average:68.83
passed: 3
failed: 1
```

here is the code I wrote for it,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab10Quiz {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
  {
    // Test cases
    readWrite("test1.txt", "out1.txt");
    readWrite("test2.txt", "out2.txt"); 
    }

/** copies the content of the srcFileName into dstFileName, and add the average of the number to the end of the dstFileName
    @param srcFileName :  souce file name contains double numbers
@param dstFileName : destination file name 
    */
    public static void readWrite(String srcFileName, String 
dstFileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
// Your code goes here
    File output = new File(dstFileName);
    PrintWriter outPut = new PrintWriter(output);

    double avg = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double tmp = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(srcFileName));
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
     tmp = in.nextDouble();
     avg += tmp;
     outPut.println(tmp);
     count ++;
    }
   avg = avg / count;
   outPut.println("Average = " + avg);
  outPut.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Did you also have a question?

Comment: As your input line consists of different data types either prompt for each one, or probably a better way would be to read the line and then split on spaces

Comment: As a beginner programmer, it's my opinion that breaking code into small parts that handle a task is a great way to solve problems. I would first, read the file, split on space like @ScaryWombat suggested, and save the file info into some type of data structures(`List` or `Array`) . I would then, loop through the data structures and do any computations and save that info into a similar data structure. I would finally, use my data structures' info to write to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code achieves what you want

```
    double avg = 0;
    int failCounter = 0;

    String[] keywords = in.nextLine().split(" ");
    int studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(keywords[0]);
    double examValue = Double.parseDouble(keywords[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < studentNumber; i++) {
        keywords = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        String studentName = keywords[0];
        double studentMark = Double.parseDouble(keywords[1]);
        double grade = calculateTotalGrade(studentMark, examValue);
        failCounter += (hasFailed(grade) ? 1 : 0);
        avg += grade;
        outPut.println(String.format("%s \t\t %.2f \t\t %s", studentName, grade, hasFailed(grade) ? "failed" : "passed"));
    }
    avg = avg / studentNumber;
    outPut.println("class average: " + avg);
    outPut.println("passed: " + (studentNumber - failCounter));
    outPut.println("failed: " + failCounter);
```

And I extracted some of the logic to below methods.

```
private static double calculateTotalGrade(double grade, double examValue) {
    return grade * 100 / examValue;
}

private static boolean hasFailed(double grade) {
    return grade < 50;
}
```

To answer how to tackle this type of questions:

1. Look for the simplest way. In this case looping for a finite iterations was easier. So I went with the for loop.
2. The counter is already given, No need to re-calculate it.
3. If you are working on a computer, write a little code and test it.
4. Do more questions like these. (if you go through the first chapters of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FG8MNN8) these questions will be easy)

Comment: Thank you it worked and appreciate the book recommendation